# git and gerrit issue while review

Tags: git, ssh, gerrit

I am working with git.

when i commit the code its fine but during the review its throwing error

```
$ git review
```

gives me following error message:

```
Is this really what you meant to do?
Type 'yes' to confirm: yes
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (28/28)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done    
To ssh://name@gerrit.company.info:29418/bdu-celery
! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/publish/master/abc_org_uk_geography (change 257 closed)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://venud@gerrit.timetric.info:29418/bdu-celery'
```

Can someone let us now how to fix this

Thanks

Comment: `git review` is not a standard git command. So someone has provided a script called `git-review` that is doing a push for you. You might want to talk to whoever provided that script for you. The warning you see is due to pushing an update to a remote branch that is not a fast-forward update. That might be ok here in which case it could be forced, but I don't know what else that script might expect. Possibly you have done a rebase and should not have.

Answer (score 0):

`git review` looks like it's a name alias of git command. I think it used wrong destination refs spec.

You can use push your code to gerrit server with right refs spec, such as

```
git push gerrit HEAD:refs/for/master
```

- **gerrit** is name of gerrit git repo
- assuming you want to push working branch to master

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is quite simple, you're trying to push to a closed review -- "(change 257 closed)".

Change 257 is identified by the Change-Id in your commit message, e.g.:

```
commit 67b36a52914afc3098d9da6750bb8f3d4a9561ac
Author: Paul Bourke <foo@bar.com>
Date:   Wed Mar 12 16:45:53 2014 +0000

    Hello World

    Change-Id: I5e6481e8c069591272d1aee5ab1197e94354ba8c
```

If you want to submit this as a new review, remove the Change-Id and git review will generate a new one:

```
git commit --amend
# delete the Change-Id line and save
git commit --amend
```